# Missing Notification Center Widgets & Share Extensions

Tags: macos, notifications, widgets

Half of my **Notification Center** widgets (most importantly, **Weather**) suddenly disappeared, and can no longer be added back by clicking **Edit** at the bottom of the **Notification Center**. Those that remain, like **Today** and **Tomorrow**, show no information.

They are also missing from **** → **System Preferences** → **Extensions** → **Today**.

I’ve tried reinstalling the **macOS 10.12.3 Combo Update**, with no success through multiple reboots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple has a [knowledge base article](https://support.apple.com/HT203129) for this bug occasionally affecting **macOS Yosemite**, **El Capitan**, and now **Sierra**. This happens most often after installing an OS update.

To reregister all **Notification Center** widgets and Share Extensions, start a **Terminal** session, and enter the following:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -seed
```

(Triple-click the above line and press <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> to copy, then <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> inside **Terminal**.)