# Missing Sharing Extensions after upgrading to an Apple Silicon Mac

Tags: macos

I recently purchased an M3 MacBook Pro (my previous computer was an Intel MacBook Pro). I used Migration Assistant to move my stuff over to my new computer. Ever since I've upgraded, all my 3rd party apps that have sharing extensions don't show up in the Share menu (I've checked both Safari and Finder, but I assume this would happen in any app). When I select `Edit Extensions...` they don't show up in that list either.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the 3rd party apps, and that didn't help.

I also tried running the Terminal command [in this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/274772/316) and that didn't help, either.

Does anyone know how to get my 3rd party sharing extensions to show up in the Share menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open System Settings
- Search for "share", click on Extensions and then on "Added extensions"
- Make sure that the extensions you need are checked